# Render/draw child of Scrollview outside Scrollview area

Tags: xaml, scrollview, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Im implementing a UI in Windows 10 (UWP) with elements that can be moved using drag and drop from a menu area to a ScrollView area, it should also be possible to move the elements back to the menu area from the ScrollView. When a element is moved from the menu to the ScrollView the element is removed as child of the menu and added as a child to a child of the ScrollView.

But when I try to move the elements back they render behind the menu. I have played around with z index and the order the elements are in the XAML and tested to remove and re add the ScrollView at run-time to put it at top, but with no luck.

Seams like ScrollView children does not draw outside the view? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Below is some sample code that illustrates the issue:

```
<Page x:Class="ScrollViewTest.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:ScrollViewTest"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="Transparent"
      Height="200"
      Width="200">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
            Canvas.ZIndex="1"
            Background="Transparent">
        <Canvas Background="Transparent"
                Height="0"
                Width="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Border Canvas.Left="-25"
                    Canvas.Top="100"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"></Border>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  Canvas.ZIndex="2"
                  Background="Transparent">
        <Canvas Background="Transparent"
                Height="0"
                Width="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Border Canvas.Left="75"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    BorderBrush="Blue"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"></Border>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And the result, I want the blue border to be shown on top of the grid

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like ScrollView children does not draw outside the view?

This is because the Content of `Grid` has a limited size which is exactly the size of itself, but the content of `ScrollViewer` has no limited size since it is scroll-able, not like a `Grid`, the child element of a `ScrollViewer` will always be rendered inside of it.

> ..., I want the blue border to be shown on top of the grid

To be honestly, I think it is not the right direction to use `Canvas.ZIndex` to implement the drag and drop gesture between different parent. A Canvas.ZIndex value is interpreted by the most immediate parent Canvas element from where the value is set. The value is used to explicitly define the draw order in cases where child elements overlap. In this case, your `Grid` and `ScrollViewer` have the same parent, but the `Canvas`s have different parent.

Here I can give you a method to implement this function:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="rootGrid"
      PointerPressed="rootGrid_PointerPressed"
      PointerReleased="rootGrid_PointerReleased">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Grid.Column="1" Background="Wheat">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" Width="50" Height="50" />
        <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red" />
    </Canvas>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Column="0"
              VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              Background="LightBlue">
        <Canvas Width="100" x:Name="canvasInsideScrollViewer">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public Page20()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += Page20_Loaded;
}

private void Page20_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gridRect = canvas.TransformToVisual(rootGrid).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, canvas.ActualWidth, canvas.ActualHeight));
    scrollViewerRect = scrollViewer.TransformToVisual(rootGrid).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, scrollViewer.ActualWidth, scrollViewer.ActualHeight));
}

private Rect gridRect;
private Rect scrollViewerRect;
private FrameworkElement MoveElement;

private void rootGrid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootGrid);
    if (gridRect.Left <= pointer.Position.X && pointer.Position.X <= gridRect.Right &&
        gridRect.Top <= pointer.Position.Y && pointer.Position.Y <= gridRect.Bottom)
    {
        foreach (var childElement in canvas.Children)
        {
            var element = childElement as FrameworkElement;
            Rect childBounds = element.TransformToVisual(rootGrid).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
            if (childBounds.Left <= pointer.Position.X && pointer.Position.X <= childBounds.Right &&
                childBounds.Top <= pointer.Position.Y && pointer.Position.Y <= childBounds.Bottom)
            {
                MoveElement = element;
                canvas.Children.Remove(element);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (scrollViewerRect.Left <= pointer.Position.X && pointer.Position.X <= scrollViewerRect.Right &&
        scrollViewerRect.Top <= pointer.Position.Y && pointer.Position.Y <= scrollViewerRect.Bottom)
    {
        foreach (var childElement in canvasInsideScrollViewer.Children)
        {
            var element = childElement as FrameworkElement;
            Rect childBounds = element.TransformToVisual(rootGrid).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
            if (childBounds.Left <= pointer.Position.X && pointer.Position.X <= childBounds.Right &&
                childBounds.Top <= pointer.Position.Y && pointer.Position.Y <= childBounds.Bottom)
            {
                MoveElement = element;
                canvasInsideScrollViewer.Children.Remove(element);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void rootGrid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootGrid);
    if (MoveElement != null)
    {
        if (gridRect.Left <= pointer.Position.X && pointer.Position.X <= gridRect.Right &&
            gridRect.Top <= pointer.Position.Y && pointer.Position.Y <= gridRect.Bottom)
        {
            var canvasPointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas);
            canvas.Children.Add(MoveElement);
            Canvas.SetLeft(MoveElement, canvasPointer.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(MoveElement, canvasPointer.Position.Y);
        }
        else if (scrollViewerRect.Left <= pointer.Position.X && pointer.Position.X <= scrollViewerRect.Right &&
            scrollViewerRect.Top <= pointer.Position.Y && pointer.Position.Y <= scrollViewerRect.Bottom)
        {
            var scrollviewPointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvasInsideScrollViewer);
            canvasInsideScrollViewer.Children.Add(MoveElement);
            Canvas.SetLeft(MoveElement, scrollviewPointer.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(MoveElement, scrollviewPointer.Position.Y);
        }
    }

    MoveElement = null;
}
```

As you can see, I changed the `Grid` in the second column to `Canvas`, so the element can be rendered in the absolute position as your mouse point. Here is the rendering image of my demo:
[image]

Here the most confusing part is that you want to translate `UIElement` between different parent controls, but if you put your `Border`s (which you want to drag and drop) also in the `rootGrid`, your `Grid`, `ScrollViewer`, `Border`s will have the same parent, then you can follow [CustomBehaviorControl](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/master/samples/CS/XAMLBehaviorsSample/CustomBehaviorControl.xaml) of [XAMLBehaviorsSample](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/tree/master/samples) to complete the drag-and-drop work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification on z-index. I realize this might not be the best solution for implementing the drag and drop functionality I want. What might not be clear from my question is that I want the elements to be visible while being dragged, this is where the problem arises.

Comment: @JonatanBlom, but can it be draged and dropped in the same parent control? It won't make any difference just from the rendered layout.